# How do I fix this cordova build error?

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build "hello world" cordova app , and I have carefully installed android studio, android SDK and other required dependencies for cordova as well as configured the right path, but I am getting this error when I am trying to build :

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VM error while Build Cordova PhoneGap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384375/vm-error-while-build-cordova-phonegap)

Answer (score 1):

Check your `path` environment variable, it should contain :

```
jdk\bin;Roaming\npm;android-sdks\platform-tools;android-sdks\tools;nodejs;nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;Git\bin
```