# How to run my app on an IONIC 3 physical device

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, ionic3

I want to run my app on a physical device HUAWEI K2-L23
but I'm not getting results ...

1.- I add the platform

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

2.- I build the app for the previous platform

```
ionic cordova build android
```

3.- I run the app in the physical device

```
ionic cordova run android
```

doing the 3-step I get the following error:

```
> cordova run android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\crisa\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

[image: Console]

I'm using Visual Studio Code ... with Ionic 3, I have Cordova installed and all its dependencies, I've also added _JAVA_OPTIONS as a system variable with the value -Xmx512M, I'm new using SQLite, that's why I want to show my app on a device physical, any help for me?

Comment: run `cordova requirements` in your project folder

Comment: you say execute some command? or verify the cordova version? @SurajRao

Comment: That command checks if all the environment dependencies are met for your app. `cordova requirements`

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

1. Close the `Visual Studio Code`
2. Reboot your PC
3. Open your project in `Visual Studio Code`
4. Try again

If above will not work then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384375/vm-error-while-build-cordova-phonegap) post on SO and try which one will work for you.

Comment: when running the command of 3. step now I throw the following error: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M @VicJordan any help for me?

Comment: @BodegaPangal remove `_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M ` from system variables and try again from step 1

Answer (score 0):

Just delete folder "Plateforms" and run  "ionic cordova run android"
[image]

Comment: after deleting the folder ... I do not add the platform? you say skip step 1.- of the question after deleting the folder?